# Rails with HAML template Engine how label works in Haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

i am new to HAML and not able to understand old coder logic 
i try to identify where the label come on ui in HAML template
this are my code 
main view page

```
  = render :partial => "application/select_search", :locals => {:n => "benefit_stream_inf", :options => @dynamic_benefit_options, :default => true}
```

select_search page which render in main plage

```
label = local_assigns[:l] ? l : t(n, :scope => local_assigns[:s] ? s : :models)
```

now i not give any label in render then how lable get generated

can some one explain this label assignment code

```
label = local_assigns[:l] ? l : t(n, :scope => local_assigns[:s] ? s : :models)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I got my answer

```
label = local_assigns[:l] ? l : t(n, :scope => local_assigns[:s] ? s : :models)
```

`local_assigns[:l]`  is a local variable which used to give label directly

`t(n, :scope => local_assigns[:s] ? s : :models)` this is used for fatch label value of translation file with pass key and scope

and translation file will put at config/local/en.yml

Comment: Great you got the answer while i'm typing.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the below statement

```
label = local_assigns[:l] ? l : t(n, :scope => local_assigns[:s] ? s : :models)
```

Operator used is ternary operator

means lable can be `"l"` or `t(n, :scope => local_assigns[:s] ? s : :models)`

by seing this

```
  = render :partial => "application/select_search", :locals => {:n => "benefit_stream_inf", :options => @dynamic_benefit_options, :default => true}
```

we can say that `local_assigns[:l]` will returns `false` means it will fall into the second option, That is `t(n, :scope => local_assigns[:s] ? s : :models)`.

`t(n, :scope => local_assigns[:s] ? s : :models)`

in above statement  `n = "benefit_stream_inf"`  and in the `scope` again we have the ternary  operator in this `local_assigns[:s]` it will returns `false` means finally `label` variable will be assigned with `t("benefit_stream_inf", :scope => :models)`

if you see the en.yml in your project `models` hash which contains the  `'benefit_stream_inf'` `key` with some `value`
this value will be assigned to the label variable, for more info about the internationalization you can see this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#looking-up-translations)

I hope it will helps.